# Raspberry Pi static IP & DHCP Server Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, dhcp, raspberrypi, netplan

I'm trying to configure my Raspberry Pi 4B running Ubuntu 18.04 with a static IP address (to then configure a DHCP server) and use the WiFi for internet traffic (routing any clients connecting to the DHCP through to the WiFi connection) but I cannot define a static IP address for the LAN, using netplan I have the config: 
`network:
        #LAN connection for ipv4 DHCP server
        version: 2
        renderer: networkd
        ethernets:
                eth0
        addresses:
               - 10.0.0.1/24
        gateway4: 10.0.0.1
        nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4.4]

```
    # LAN connection ipv6 - using for DHCP Server
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
            eth0:
    addresses:
            - 2001:1::1/64
    gateway6: 2001:1::2
    nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4]

    # wifi connection
    wifis:
            wlan0
    dhcp4: true
    dhcp6: true
    access-points:
            "SSID-name"
    password: "WiFi Password"
```

I keep getting indentation errors when I try to apply the plan.  The indentation is that which is created when I manually type in the details.

```
sudo netplan -debug generate
/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:11:17: Error in network definition: expected mapping (check indentation)
                eth0
                ^
```

Comment: Netplan is very specific about indentation. It works with the indentation IT wants and not with the indentation YOU want. I suggest that you refer to the provided examples here and amend your yaml file accordingly: https://netplan.io/examples Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I was referring to netplan.io/examples (one of the first places I looked for info) and it wasn't very helpful.  All indentations were created whenever I hit the 'enter' key and began typing the new line. I've finally managed to create a working config.  

I had a few issues trying to get the WiFi to be the default network configuration but have resolved that also.  I'll see if I can upload my working netplan file.

Comment: It would be nice to know what you did to get the configuration working :-)

Comment: The attached netplan in the answer is what I did.  That config resulted in a working DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

This is my currently working netplan file.  I've managed also to set the WiFi as the default internet connection  which is what I want in order to use the eth0 connection for the DHCP server (once that's installed).

```
    network:
    # wifi connection
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    wifis:
            wlan0:
                    dhcp4: true
                    dhcp6: true
                    access-points:
                            "SSID-Name":
                                    password: "password"

    #LAN connection for ipv4 DHCP server
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
            eth0:
                    dhcp4: no
                    addresses:
                            - 10.0.0.1/24
                    nameservers:
                            addresses: [8.8.8.8,4.4.4.4]

    # LAN connection ipv6 - using for DHCP Server
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
            eth0:
                    dhcp6: no
                    addresses:
                         - 2001:1::1/64
                    nameservers:
                            addresses: [8.8.8.8,4.4.4.4]
```

I also opted to set NetworkManager as the renderer because I plan to use the GUI on this Pi so will be able to see at a glance what the WiFi status is.